# Cannot run Algorithm from Toolbox in QGIS - Failed to create file

Tags: qgis, vector

I am on QGIS 3.16.3 and I want to use the `Split Vector` Algorithm.
I have an Input Geometry which I got through the Overpass API from OSM https://overpass-turbo.eu/. The query is

```
node
  [amenity=school]
  (52.29084259241063,12.94189453125,52.722153756528385,13.907318115234375);
out;
```

When I import this layer into QGIS, convert it into a `SHP` and then run the "Split Vector Layer" algorithm from the toolbox on it, I get the following

> Algorithmus Split Vectorlayer startet…
> Input parameter:
> { 'FIELD' : 'id', 'FILE_TYPE' : 1, 'INPUT' : 'C:/.../gis2/python/code/schools.shp', 'OUTPUT' : 'C:\...\schools' }
>
> Create Layer: C:...\schools\id_node/549928511.shp Could not create
> Layer C:...\schools\id_node/549928511.shp nicht erzeugen: Create
> Layer failed (OGR-Fehler: Failed to create file
> C:...\schools\id_node\549928511.shp: No such file or directory) Failed
> after 0.03 Sekonds
>
> Load resulting Layer
>
> Algorithm 'Split Vector Layer' terminated

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Have you tried running the algorithm directly from the result of the query, without saving it first? Have you tried using geopackage as you output-file type?

Comment: @Erik If I try the `geopackage` as output file I get `>unable to open database file`. What do you mean by this "Have you tried running the algorithm directly from the result of the query, without saving it first"?

Comment: You said you converted the json to shp. What happens when you don't do this?

Comment: @Erik The same error... Just as with a `shp`

Comment: Have you made sure the field `id` actually contains an ID? Because I ran your query with the OSM plugin and there was no field called `id` - but `full id` for example. Split vector worked flawlessly using that field.

Answer (score 1):

One should use a unique id to allow `Split vector` to work correctly.

I tried the following and it worked:

- export the `KML` file produced by overpass-turbo to a GeoPackage format.
- In the process, the `fid` field was created.
- Using it in `Split vector` makes it work.
- On the opposite, if I run `split vector` on the original `_id` field, it fails with an error similar to the one reported in the question:

[image]